# Order-by on more than one column in hbm.xml

Tags: hibernate

we are using hibernate hbm.xml as configuration files. And want to sort on 2 columns one is position which is integer and if they are same then it has to sort on name (string alphabetically). can order-by on more than one column in hbm.xml.

Comment: Could any one suggest if its possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```
order-by="property1 asc,property2 asc"
```